# Performance impact disabling adaptive sampling in app service?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm running an app service (ASP.NET 7) and I'm using default settings for application insights. I've recently learned that by defauult, Adaptive Sampling is enabled. I've noticed that when traffic spikes to my app, I'm missing logs that would be useful for debugging. I'd like to disable adaptive sampling. But first, I'd like to understand if there's any potential for this change to have an adverse effect on the performance of my app service instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that any performance penalty is noticeable. The telemetry is already caputered anyway and the decision to discard data due to sampling is done on a background thread, as is sending the data using batches. There will be a (small?) increase of network traffic but that's about it.

Adaptive sampling isn't so much about web app performance as it is about managing the costs of the Azure resource as you pay for the volume of data ingested and stored.

Comment: hi Peter, In the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling 
It clearly states that "Ingestion sampling works on the Application Insights service endpoint. It only applies when no other sampling is in effect. If the SDK samples your telemetry, ingestion sampling is disabled."
Since the adaptive sampling is by default enabled, can I understand that even Ingestion sampling doesn't operate while adaptive is in operation. That is to say, even it's 100% by default (Go to specific app insights ->Usage and estimated costs->Data sampling), it's being ignored.

Comment: Also, if I disable adaptive sampling in ConfigSerivice as the document suggests, it costs when the code is deployed, for the volumne of data ingested/stored, correct?

Comment: @jumpingbunny Yes, if adaptive sampling is disabled you par for data ingested/stored. You can then either use ingestion sampling to reduce the telemetry that is ingested and/or you can set a daily cap that is always enforced, no matter what type of sampling is enabled or disabled.